# Convert String to good string in minimum moves

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a string S of 0 and 1 we need to convert it into a good string. A string is called good if and only if:

**There are no two or more 0s or 1s together. It means 001 is not good but 010 is a good string.**

Now we can swap positions of any two indexes of S. Let the cost of swapping from position i with position j (i≠j) be C(i,j).

Now we have two types of costs calculation :

1. C(i,j)=|j−i|
2. C(i,j)=|j−i|*|j−i|

**We need to find minimum cost of swaps needed to convert the current string S into a good string.**

Also if its not possible to convert string S into good string then also we need to tell that like if S=00 then we can never convert it into good string.

**Example** : Let string S=0011 then if cost is of type 1 that is we can swap any two positions and cost will |j−i| then answer is 1 and also for type 2 cost as (3−2)^2=1

What can be DP solution for this problem as |S|<=10^5 instead of brute solution . Please help me find recurrence for this problem to find minimum cost

Comment: If I understand the definition correctly, being *good* means that zeros and ones alternate. Is that right?

Comment: As a start, four cases have to be distinguished. let `0(s)` and `1(s)` denote the number of zeros and ones in `s`, respectively. *Case 1:* `|0(s)-1(s)|>1`, then `s` cannot be converted to a good string. *Case 2:* `0(s) = 1(s)+1`, then `s` can only be converted in a good string which starts with `0`. *Case 3:* `0(s) = 1(s)-1`, then `s` can only be converted into a good string which starts with `1`. *Case 4:* `0(s)=1(s)`, then `s` can be converted into both good strings which start with `0` and `1`.

Comment: @Codor But I not only need to tell weather it can be converted to good string or not. I need to ind minimum cost too to convert it to good string

Comment: Yes, I understood the question, I'm thinking about it.

Comment: @Codor Yeah ok.Me too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72410/discussion-between-codor-and-doremoon).

Comment: Was this another question from that live contest? You should be ashamed. *You're* the one competing.

Answer (score 1):

Correct if I am wrong, but there can be at most two solutions.

If the number of 0s and 1s is equal, we have two solutions, one starting with 0 and another with 1. Otherwise, there is only one solution: start and end with abundant digit. And there is no solution if the difference in counts is more than 1.

For each case you can calculate the cost trivially.

Eg. If we need to swap a 1 at location 0, find the next immediate extra 0 and swap with it. This solution is the optimal for all 3 cases you mentioned.

Comment: Post some peudocode and also explanation for your algorithm. As am not sure it will provide minimum result

Comment: example `1110100,` swap first 'incorrect' `1` with 'incorrect' `0`, and you will swap it for the last one; `1010101` with C=6-1=5. if you don't believe it, disprove it, pseudocode is not gonna help you.

Comment: @ElKamina And can you please explain "find the next immediate extra 0"